# Github Action treats a succesful ` gcloud build ` as a failure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions

I have a very small project where I'm setting up GH Actions to build using Google Cloud Build, with Buildpacks, and deploying with Google Cloud Run.

In my workflow I have this step:

```
      # Build and push image to Google Container Registry
      - name: Build Image
        working-directory: ./backend
        run: |-
          gcloud builds submit --pack image=${{ vars.SERVER_IMAGE }}
```

When the action is run I get these logs:

```
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Build Image'
##[debug]Evaluating: success()
##[debug]Evaluating success:
##[debug]=> true
##[debug]Result: true
##[debug]Starting: Build Image
##[debug]Loading inputs
##[debug]Evaluating: format('gcloud builds submit --pack image=***0***', vars.SERVER_IMAGE)
##[debug]Evaluating format:
##[debug]..Evaluating String:
##[debug]..=> 'gcloud builds submit --pack image=***0***'
##[debug]..Evaluating Index:
##[debug]....Evaluating vars:
##[debug]....=> Object
##[debug]....Evaluating String:
##[debug]....=> 'SERVER_IMAGE'
##[debug]..=> 'europe-north1-docker.pkg.dev/**Redacted**'
##[debug]=> 'gcloud builds submit --pack image=**Redacted**r'
##[debug]Result: 'gcloud builds submit --pack image=**Redacted**'
##[debug]Loading env
Run gcloud builds submit --pack image=europe-north1-docker.pkg.dev/**Redacted**
 gcloud builds submit --pack image=europe-north1-docker.pkg.dev/**Redacted**
 shell: /usr/bin/bash -e ***0***
 env: **Redacted**

##[debug]/usr/bin/bash -e /home/runner/work/_temp/66386e53-d7d1-4e54-be36-0461c8fdc0be.sh
Creating temporary tarball archive of 177 file(s) totalling 48.9 MiB before compression.
Uploading tarball of [.] to [gs://**Redacted**_cloudbuild/source/1678965338.099448-94b89c848a0b4dc9b[2](https://github.com/davidals/**Redacted**/actions/runs/4435738713/jobs/7784789787#step:6:2)e6b[3](https://github.com/davidals/**Redacted**/actions/runs/4435738713/jobs/7784789787#step:6:3)da[4](https://github.com/davidals/**Redacted**/actions/runs/4435738713/jobs/7784789787#step:6:4)2d0330f.tgz]
Created [https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/**Redacted**/locations/global/builds/9[5](https://github.com/davidals/**Redacted**/actions/runs/4435738713/jobs/7784789787#step:6:5)cbf910-2439-4a97-b[6](https://github.com/davidals/**Redacted**/actions/runs/4435738713/jobs/7784789787#step:6:6)01-90e9b38ee0af].
Logs are available at [ https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/95cbf910-2439-4a9[7](https://github.com/davidals/**Redacted**/actions/runs/4435738713/jobs/7784789787#step:6:7)-b601-90e9b3[8](https://github.com/davidals/**Redacted**/actions/runs/4435738713/jobs/7784789787#step:6:8)ee0af?project=[9](https://github.com/davidals/**Redacted**/actions/runs/4435738713/jobs/7784789787#step:6:9)9[15](https://github.com/davidals/**Redacted**/actions/runs/4435738713/jobs/7784789787#step:6:15)[34](https://github.com/davidals/**Redacted**/actions/runs/4435738713/jobs/7784789787#step:6:34)9594[36](https://github.com/davidals/**Redacted**/actions/runs/4435738713/jobs/7784789787#step:6:36) ].
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) 
The build is running, and logs are being written to the default logs bucket.
This tool can only stream logs if you are Viewer/Owner of the project and, if applicable, allowed by your VPC-SC security policy.

The default logs bucket is always outside any VPC-SC security perimeter.
If you want your logs saved inside your VPC-SC perimeter, use your own bucket.
See https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/store-manage-build-logs.

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
##[debug]Finishing: Build Image
```

But if I go to the logs on Cloud build side of things, it shows that the build was succesful:

[image]

And the image was created and uploaded as expected.

But the action completed as a failure and the following steps did not run.
Did I miss anything?

Comment: I think the error comes from the fact the logs are not being streamed rather than the build itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have enough permissions to stream logs from Cloud Build to Github Actions, what you can do is to suppress logs. You can add this to your `cloudbuild.yaml` to [store build logs in both Logging and Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/store-manage-build-logs):

```
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

Or, you can pass [`--suppress-logs`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit#--suppress-logs) parameter to your `gcloud` command:

```
  # Build and push image to Google Container Registry
  - name: Build Image
    working-directory: ./backend
    run: |-
      gcloud builds submit --pack image=${{ vars.SERVER_IMAGE }} --suppress-logs
```

Comment: Hey @fcman5, thanks for the answer.

Tried suppressing the logs, but the error remains the same.
Also tried the options, but i'm not sure if it got picked up since this is a Github Action workflow yaml, not a Google Cloud Build yaml.

Comment: Adding the permissions worked. Thanks @Fcmam5

Comment: @DavidAnderson I assume the permissions you're talking about is Project -> viewer? Did you add it to the cloud build service account?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specifically rely on google cloud build, you can skip using `gcloud builds submit` and use docker instead to build the image locally and then push it into GCP:

```yaml
- name: Configure docker for GCP
  run: gcloud auth configure-docker
- name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: gcr.io/${{vars.CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME}}/${{ vars.SERVER_IMAGE }}:latest
```